How to programming call a Pytest BDD file
I was looking into how I would call this Pytest BDD file from another Python file and record the results of its completion. At present, it is called CMD py -m pytest -vvv -q steps.py -o log_cli=true --log-cli-level=DEBUG --capture=tee-sys --feature=Test  --alluredir allure-results. (Sorry, would post more code, but stack overflow is not letting me.)
import teradatasql,pytest,logging,re,warnings,sys,allure

from typing import List, Dict
from ApplicationProperties import ApplicationProperties as AP
import StringBuilder,AllureReports

from pytest_bdd import given,when,then,scenarios, parsers
import pandas as pd

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore') 

COL_DELIM = "|"
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
ROW_MAX_LENGTH = 100

props = AP()
shost = props.getDbHost()
suser = props.getDbUser()

spassword = props.getDbPass()
slogmech = props.getDbLogMech()

environment=props.getEnvironment()

featurefilename = "../features/"

n = len(sys.argv)
for i in range(1, n):
    if "--feature" in sys.argv[i]:
        args = sys.argv[i]
        argRemoveParameter = args.split("=")
        featurefilename = featurefilename +argRemoveParameter[1]

LOG.debug(featurefilename)
scenarios(featurefilename)

actusult = None

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def setUp():
    conn = getConnection()
    yield conn
    #def tearDown():
        #global conn
    #close(conn)
    #request.addfinalizer(tearDown)
    
#problems here not parses examples table
@given(parsers.parse("{parameters}"), target_fixture="parameters",converters={"parameters": str})
def ParseParmeters(parameters):
    return parameters

@when(parsers.parse("I execute the query:\n{queryTemplate}"), target_fixture="actualResult")
@when(parsers.parse("SQL to execute:\n{queryTemplate}"), target_fixture="actualResult")
def whenIExecuteTheQuery(setUp,parameters,queryTemplate):
    global LOG
    LOG.debug("QueryTemplate=" + queryTemplate + "/n Parameters: " + parameters)
    query = populateParameters(parameters, queryTemplate)
    print(query)
    addSqlAsAttachment("query", query)
    LOG.debug("Executing query:" + query)
    try:
        stat = setUp
        #rs = stat.execute(query)
        rs = pd.read_sql(query, stat)
        LOG.debug("Got result: \n" + rs.to_string())
        #actualResult =asMaps(rs)
        #LOG.debug("Got result: \n" + actualResult)
        return rs
    except Exception as error:
        LOG.error("Error executing query: " + query, error)
        raise Exception(error)
    finally:
        close(stat)
        
    

@then(parsers.parse("EXPECTED_RESULT={expectedResult}"))
def actiontaken(actualResult, expectedResult):
    #used to be called then
    global LOG
    LOG.debug("expectedResult=" + expectedResult + "/n text: " + actualResult.to_string())
    if ("NO_ROWS_RETURNED".upper() == expectedResult.upper()):
        assert actualResult is not None, "Result set is not empty: " + actualResult.to_string()
    else:
        AssertionError("Unsupported EXPECTED_RESULT token!")
    

@then("I will get empty result set")
def actiontaken(actualResult):
    #used to be called then
    global LOG
    LOG.debug("Result" + actualResult.to_string())
    assert actualResult is not None, "Result set is not empty: " + actualResult.to_string()

@then(parsers.parse("I will get the following result set: {result}"))
def thenIWillGetTheFollowingResult(actualResult,expectedTable):
    ##expect a parser of table to be here ##
    expectedTableString = createTable(expectedTable.getRows())
    actualTableString = createTable(actualResult)
    expectedResult = [expectedTable.getRows()]
    for expected in expectedResult:
        for actual in actualResult:
            if expected == actual:
                actualResult.remove(actual)
                expectedResult.remove(expected)    
    tablereturn = StringBuilder()
    tablereturn.append("Expected:\n" + expectedTableString);
    tablereturn.append("\nActual:\n" + actualTableString);
    if actualResult.size() > 0:
        unexpectedTableString = createTable(actualResult);
        tablereturn.append("\nUnexpected:\n" + unexpectedTableString);
        
    if expectedResult.size() > 0:
        notFound = createTable(expectedResult);
        tablereturn.append("\nNot Found:\n" + notFound);
    #send to allure reports
    allure.attach( str(tablereturn),"ResultSets",attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.TXT);
    #ExamplesAwareReporter.addTextAttachment("ResultSets.txt", str(tablereturn));
    assert actualResult is None and expectedResult is None ,"Unexpected rows count:" + actualResult.size() + "; Not found rows count: " + expectedResult.size()



    


You can use
pytest.main("steps.py", "-vvv", "-q" , "-o", "log_cli=true", "--log-cli-level=DEBUG","--capture=tee-sys","--feature=Test","--alluredir allure-results")

